# SAP ABAP CRATING TABLES

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I'm creating a table and I've inserted the following fields:

- MATERIAL CODES (MARA-MATNR)
- Type of GAS (MARM-MEINH)

but I'm having problems with the 'CO2 coefficient' field.
Any help for the domain and Data Element of the field ?

Answer (score 0):

CO2 coefficient field not exist in SAP data elements. You should be create domain and data element by using SE11 t-code.